# Filtro de palavras: Não diferenciar maiúscula, minusculas e acentuadas

Tags: php

Preciso de um sistema de filtro de palavras de um texto, porém, não acho nenhuma forma de não diferenciar as letras entre maiúscula, minuscula e acentuadas. 
 Exemplo de texto:

> O FoGo está alto! Como vou apagar esse FÔgÓ? O fOGo está alto?

Preciso de ela filtre a palavra fogo e substitua por água. O resultado ficaria:

> O água está alto! Como vou apagar esse água? O água está alto?

OBS: As palavras a serem filtradas estão em uma tabela no banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que o `str_ireplace` seria suficiente para maiúsculo e minusculo, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-ireplace.php.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nisso](https://ideone.com/b8zkI5), já é um começo. @Inkeliz

Comment: O proprio `str_ireplace` indicado pelo Inkeliz permite receber uma lista de elementos a procurar e as suas respetivas substituições. Logo da para fazer tudo apenas com uma chamada à função

Comment: O WordPress tem uma função `remove_accents` que implementa algo parecido (na verdade remove os acentos, mas é um jeito de começar). Você pode ver a implementação aqui: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_accents/